# Github Actions SSH issue

Tags: ssh, github-actions, cicd, ssh-keys, public-key

I am using GitHub Actions, and trying to build and deploy my project using a self hosted runner. I have added the required SS_KEY in my Github repository secret and other secrets as well such as USER_ID and SERVER_IP.

I can manually doing SSH from the runner instance and make deployment without issues.

But I cant deploy the same from actions due to permission issue.

My actions.yaml

```
    name: myproject
    on:
      push:
      workflow_dispatch:
    concurrency:
      group: "${{ github.ref }}"
      cancel-in-progress: true

    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: read

    env:
      USER_ID: "${{ secrets.USER_ID }}"
      SS_KEY: "${{ secrets.SS_KEY }}"
      SERVER_IP: "${{ secrets.SERVER_IP }}""
      
    jobs:
      dev-build:
        runs-on:
          - self-hosted
        container:    
          image: ghcr.io/yepme/skanska:1.8  
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/feature-branch'
        timeout-minutes: 60
        steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        - run: |
            which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -yqq ) &&
            eval $(ssh-agent -s) &&
            echo "$SS_KEY" | ssh-add - &&
            echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config &&
            echo "$SS_KEY" > key.pem && chmod 400 key.pem &&
            ansible-playbook deploy/deploy.yml -i hosts --extra-vars '{"project":"shopping","component":"customer"}' --tags "build"
        - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3.1.3
          if: success()
          with:
            name: "${{ github.job }}"
            path: build/build.tar.gz        
            
      dev-deploy:
        needs: dev-build
        runs-on:
          - self-hosted
        container:
          image: ghcr.io/yepme/skanska:1.8      
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/feature-branch'
        timeout-minutes: 60
        steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3.0.2
        - run: |
            which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -yqq ) &&
            eval $(ssh-agent -s) &&
            echo "$SS_KEY" | ssh-add - &&
            echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config &&
            echo "$SS_KEY" > key.pem && chmod 400 key.pem &&
            pwd &&
            ls -la &&  
            
            # getting error here 
            ssh -p 2069 $AZUREGID@$AZURE_DEVRULEENGINESERVERIP "echo $AZURE_DEVRULEENGINECONFIG > /tmp/config.ini; mkdir -p ~/.cassandra/.certs; echo $AZ_DEV_CASS_CERT > ~/.cassandra/.certs/dev_cass.cer.pem; echo $AZURE_DEV_CASS_KEY > ~/.cassandra/.certs/dev_cass.key.pem"
            echo "[node]" > hosts &&
            echo "$SERVER_IP ansible_ssh_port=2069 ansible_ssh_user=$USER_ID ansible_ssh_private_key_file=./key.pem" >> hosts &&
            cat hosts > unauth_usage &&
            ansible-playbook deploy/deploy.yml -i unauth_usage --extra-vars '{"project":"shopping","component":"customer","process":"customer_max","dir":"customer","env":"dev"}' --tags "unauth_monitor" &&
            ansible-playbook deploy/deploy.yml -i hosts --extra-vars '{"project":"shopping","component":"customer","process":"customer_max","dir":"customer","env":"dev"}' --tags "deploy"
```

The error is

```
    Warning: Permanently added '[***]:2069' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
    ***@***: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: When you manually SSH from the runner instance to the server, are you using the same key as the action (the one uploaded to `SS_KEY`)?

Comment: Yes the same key